# Cannot understand command line scripts of package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to nodejs and its related technologies and trying to use it with webpack dev server and react js to run my website on windows machine. I have some commands in my package.json which I copied from some websites in internet such as :

```
webpack -d && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/index.html\" /F /Y && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback --port 3003
```

or

```
"build:prod": "webpack -p && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/\" /F /Y"
```

Which build my whole script object:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register --reporter dot --recursive",
"start": "npm run build",
"build": "webpack -d && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/index.html\" /F /Y && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback --port 3003",
"build:prod": "webpack -p && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/\" /F /Y"
```

}

It is working fine and I can interpret some part of the lines and some of commands such as F Y or -d are unclear for me.
Although everything is working I do not have a good feeling about it since I do not have a clear understanding of what is going on. I searched the web for some documentation but I could not find anything useful or maybe I do not search in the right way. Is there any good documentation that can shed light on this?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/cli

Comment: @KevinB Thanks a lot. It is a good starting point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
webpack -p && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/\" /F /Y
```

1. [`webpack`](http://webpack.github.io)
2. `-p` (`--production`)
3. `&&` (then)
4. [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) (Windows Copy File and Directories)
5. `"..."`(source) `"..."` (dest)
6. `/F` (Display full source and destination file names while copying.)
7. `/Y` (Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file.)

Comment: You SHOULD, and I don't plan to rewrite what I had now. Suffice to say, it's your own advice as it applies to your answer.

Comment: Yours is not a constructive approach.

Comment: Hitmands Thanks a lot though I do not get why the answer gets negative points. However thanks since I really needed this as an starting point

Comment: Stackoverflow is populated by disposable people, by the way this is not always true. If the answer is correct, you should accept it in order to help future people.

Comment: Thanks again. So if I want to search and learn these commands I should search for windows commands. Am right? or is there any node related commands?

Comment: They are `windows commands` because you run them in `cmd`, so, you should have a look at http://ss64.com/nt/. Others (webpack/webpack-dev-server are `cmd-let` and provide their own apis).